# Implementing reordering of TCP packets

Tags: c, tcp

Imagine a PCAP file `file` with only one connection between the client `client` and the server `server`. There are no duplicated packets, no packet loss and the packets are correctly ordered.

How can I order the packets programmatically if the packets in `file` are played in any order **without using the packets' timestamps**? (for example, starting from the last packet).

At the moment I have two queues with packets, the transmission queue (packets sent from `client`) and the reception queue (packets sent from `server`). I know I cannot know who is the `client` until I find a packet with the flag `SYN` and without the flag `ACK`.

For ordering the packets in the same queue:

1. A bigger `SEQ` number means that the packet arrived afterwards (ignoring SEQ wrapping).
2. If two packets have the same `SEQ` number, I compare the `ACK` numbers.

   - A bigger `ACK` number means that the packet arrived afterwards.
   - If the packets have the same `ACK` number I do **(and I don't know if this is correct)**:

     - If one packet have the `FIN` flag, it arrived afterwards.
     - If one packet have the `PSH` flag, it arrived afterwards.

Once the packets are (hopefully) rightly ordered in the respective queues I start to iterate through both queues (`q1` and `q2`):

```
/* If q1 and q2 are not empty... */
if SEQ number in the queue q1 < ACK number in the queue q2
    take packet p in q1
else if SEQ number in the queue q1 == ACK number in the queue q2
    if ACK number in the queue q1 < SEQ number in the queue q2
        take packet p in q1
    else if ACK number in the queue q1 == SEQ number in the queue q2
        /* I have implemented this based on what I have seen in file. */

        if FIN bit in the queue q1 && FIN bit in the queue q2
            /* Compare previous SEQ numbers in both queues, is this correct? */
            if the SEQ number of the current packet in q1 is the same as the SEQ number of the previous packet in q1
                take packet p in q1
            else
                take packet p in q2
            endif
        else if FIN bit in the queue q1
            take packet p in q2
        else if FIN bit in the queue q1
            take packet p in queue q1
        else
            /* What to do? Is this combination possible? */
        endif
    else
        take packet p in q2
    endif
else
    take packet p in q2
endif

show packet p
```

Comparing the `SEQ` number in one queue with the `ACK` number in the other queue and the other way around is the basic thing.

What I don't know is what to do when `(SEQ in q1 == ACK in q2) and (ACK in q1 == SEQ in q2)`. What I have implemented is based in the observation of two PCAP files.

What would be the correct way to do it (if possible)?

Comment: This cannot happen. Once you factor out the initial sequence numbers, for each party SEQ is number of bytes sent and ACK is number of bytes received so far. You can receive N bytes only *after* the other party sends N bytes. So in your scenario each of the two packets comes after the other.

Comment: I know it shouldn't happen in real. I want to read a PCAP file with only one TCP connection in which the packets are in any order and see whether I manage to order them so that it matches the original file (the one in which the packets are correctly ordered).